# Multiple "default" properties/methods in a VB6 class?

Tags: dictionary, vb6, default

I am trying to make a replacement VB6 class for the Scripting.Dictionary class from SCRRUN.DLL.  Scripting.Dictionary has (among other things) a "Keys" method that returns an array of keys, and a read/write "Item" property that returns the item associated with a key.  I am confused about this, because both of them seem to be defaults for the class.  That is:

```
For Each X In MyDict
```

Is equivalent to:

```
For Each X In MyDict.Keys
```

Which to me implies that "Keys" is the default operation for the class, but:

```
MyDict("MyKey") = "MyValue"
MsgBox MyDict("MyKey")
```

Is equivalent to:

```
MyDict.Item("MyKey") = "MyValue"
MsgBox MyDict.Item("MyKey")
```

Which to me implies that "Item" is the default operation for the class.

I've never before created a VB6 class that had a default operation, so upon realizing this, I thought perhaps I could define multiple default operations as long as they all have different signatures, which they do: Keys is nullary, the Item getter takes a Variant, and the Item setter takes two Variants.  But this doesn't seem to be allowed: When I use "Tools/Procedure Attributes" to set the Keys function to be the default, and then I use it to set the Item property to be the default, the IDE complains that a default has already been set.

So I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here.  What is going on in the Scripting.Dictionary object that makes it able to act as if "Keys" is the default in some contexts, but as if "Item" is the default in others? And whatever it is, can I accomplish the same thing in VB6?

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering my own question: I haven't tried this yet, but I gather that "Item" should be made the default, and that I should add an entirely new function called "NewEnum" that looks something like the following (slightly modified from an example in Francesco Balena's "Programming Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0" book):

```
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = m_Keys.[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

(where "m_Keys" is a Collection containing the keys), and then use Tools/Procedure Attributes to hide NewEnum and to set its ProcID to -4.

Comment: @Bob77 has a good point -- there is actually quite a lot of good information in the provider Programmer's Guide. You can access it from the docs that were shipped with it or [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204616.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is the difference between the default member and a collection enumerator. A COM object (including VB6 classes) can have both.

You can identify the default property of a class by looking in the Object Browser for the tiny blue globe or the words "default member of" in the description (see [Contents of the Object Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240859%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). The Object Browser will not identify an enumerator method, but if you look at the class's interface definition using OLE View or [TypeLib Browser](http://com.it-berater.org/) (free but registration required) it's [DispId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be 0xfffffffc or -4.

In your own class, you can mark the default property by setting the Procedure ID to "(default)" in the Procedure Attributes dialog (see [Making a Property or Method the Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263533%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). You already listed the steps for setting up the collection enumerator in your own answer, but you can find this listed as well in the Programmer's Guide topic [Creating Your Own Collection Class: The House of Bricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262338%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually the Object Browser *will indeed* show an enumerator.  You just have to turn on "show hidden members."

Comment: @Bob77 Yes, but even if you are looking at hidden members, it doesn't specifically flag it that it is set as the enumerator.

Answer (score -1):

Scripting.Dictionary has a dirty secret:

It does not handle enumeration at all, it returns big ugly Variant arrays and your For Each loops iterate over those.

This is one of the reasons why a Dictionary can actually be far less efficient than a standard VB6 Collection.

Comment: Does your simple fact address the question being asked.

Comment: This prints "Unknown" in immediate window: https://gist.github.com/wqweto/7952402